# How to replace dot in property file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

First of all I have seen questions similar to this one.I have followed the solutions from those threads.But still im not able to fix it.I want to remove dots(.) from the key of the property file .Can some one help to identify the issue

I have a property file  tempds.properties

```
#Fri Jan 30 07:37:25 CET 2015
ds.home=/opt/abc
mykey=/opt/xyz
```

I use another script test.sh

```
cd /opt
chmod 777 tempds.properties

#awk -F= -vOFS="=" 'gsub(/\./,"_",$1)+1' tempds.properties
cat tempds.properties| sed 's/\./_/g' > .tempds.properties


echo "Processing  "
for i in {1..5}; do
    sleep 1
    echo "..........."


done

. /opt/tempds.properties
echo $ds_home
echo $mykey
echo "Process finishd"
```

Output :

```
root@onebox:/opt# sudo ./test.sh
Processing
...........
./test.sh: 2: /opt/tempds.properties: ds.home=/opt/abc: not found

/opt/xyz
Process finishd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `.tempds.properties` from `tempds.properties` but then you still invoke `tempds.properties`.

You may skip creating the temporary file altogether:

```
eval `sed 's/\./_/g' tempds.properties`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace dots by `tr` command,

```
tr '.' '_' .tempds.properties
```